# Variables from CSV Data Set Config

Tags: csv, variables, jmeter

In JMeter I add csv file to the CSV Data Set Config. csv file has 2 columns - ID and Database. Each column has 50 items. In JMeter number of threads I put 50 users too. In the first HTTP request I change parameters due to the variable ${ID} [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM5id.png) and in the next HTTP request I change the variable ${Database} [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5LPs.png). But when I run the test, in JMeter the number of users is increasing, but in the real my program there is no users.
But when I load csv file only for ID or only for Database with the only one column and when I change only one variable ( ${ID} or ${Database} ), users are appears in my real program or different database are choosen.

So where is the problem, that it is do not work please? I need to make a test where each user with each ID have to go to corresponding database. Thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0RQc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In its current form your question cannot be comprehensively answered.

We need to see:

1. First 2 lines of your CSV file
2. Your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup
3. Variables in [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)
4. Request details in View Results Tree listener
5. [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file

If you cannot share the above information as it's sensitive - use the above hints for troubleshooting.

Example setup:

- Given you have `test.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation which looks like:

  ```
   ID,Database
   foo,bar
   baz,qux
  ```
- And CSV Data Set Config which looks like:

  [image]
- each virtual user will pick new line on each iteration and read the values from the CSV into `${ID}` and `${Database}` variables

  [image]